# Left aligned page numbers in table of content in MS Word

Tags: ms-word

In MS Word I want to place page numbers in Table of Contents to the left as opposed to the right which is the standard format.

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Not relevant to stackoverflow